# 404 errors on cpresources images

Tags: control-panel

i'm facing 404 errors for images related files in the control panel
like users photo, Login Page Logo, site Icon... etc...

for user photo for example i can edit the image, and i see it normally, but it is not visible on the my account page when craft try to reach 
http://domaine.org/craft/cpresources/102e2477/thumb-100x100.jpg?v=1524146432

cpresources rights are 755

any help welcome :)

Comment: What version of Craft are you on?

Comment: last release 3.0.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed for the next release. Only affects environments where the web server is not sending missing resource requests (like `/cpresources/XXXXXX/logo.svg`) to `index.php`.